# Run code inside a string with python .format

Tags: python, eval

I need to use code saved in a string (tmp_str) inside .format ?

```
tmp_str="ID='ID_VAR_DICT'"
    
sql_text="SELECT FIELD FROM TABLE_A WHERE ID = {ID}"
sql_query = sql_text.format(ID='ID_VAR_DICT')
print ('sql_query -->',sql_query) #Print A
    
sql_query = sql_text.format(eval(tmp_str))
print ('sql_query -->',sql_query) #Print B
```

Basically I need #Print B to output the same as #Print A but passing the contents off tmp_str to .format

Output:

```
('sql_query -->', 'SELECT FIELD FROM TABLE_A WHERE ID = ID_VAR_DICT')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_testes.py", line 7, in <module>      
    sql_query = sql_text.format(eval(tmp_str))
  File "<string>", line 1
    ID='ID_VAR_DICT'
```

Thanks in advance,
M

Comment: Do not use string formatting to create SQL queries. Do something like `cursor.execute('SELECT FIELD FROM TABLE_A WHERE ID=?', ('ID_VAR_DICT',))`.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a recommendation -- as chepner says in a comment, you should use a prepared statement with parameters.

But if you really need to do it your way, you have to eval the entire expression, not just the argument.

```
sql_query = eval(f'sql_text.format({tmp_str})')
```